# how to use nested for loop to get the data Last Value Not be duplicated in dictionary or list

Tags: python, for-loop, nested-loops

Would you help me how to get the data not duplicated.
i'd appreciated it if you're giving an idea for me to solve the problem

**OUTPUT(Expected) IS  ['A' : [1,2,3,4], 'B' : [5,6,7,8]]
BUT, THE DATA printed  ['A' : [5,6,7,8], 'B' : [5,6,7,8]]
B's Values repeated in A **

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

Lotno_list = ['A','B']

count_merge = []
total_count = []
total_dict = {}

for Lotno in Lotno_list:
  folder_list = os.listdir(r'../{}/'.format(Lotno)) # get the folder_list in the folder (Lotno) 
  count_merge.clear()
  for element in folder_list: # ex) folder_list = ['A01','A02','A03','A04'] when Lotno = 'A'into for
    element_list = os.listdir(r'../{}/{}/'.format(Lotno,element)) 
    element_count = len(element_list)
    # Count files in the folder A01 = 1, A02 = 2 ...
    count_merge.append(element_count) # ex) A = [1,2,3,4] , B = [5,6,7,8]
  total_dict[Lotno] = count_merge
print(total_dict)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the more important concepts in Python.  You don't recreate `count_merge`, you just clear it and refill it.  That means your `total_dict` does not contain two separate lists.  Instead, it contains several references to the EXACT SAME LIST.  Changing one of them will change them all.

To make this work, you must create a new list in your loop.  Just replace `count_merge.clear()` with `count_merge = []`, and it should work.